# Updating file paths in excel/vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula in an excel workbook that pulls data from another workbook as part of a macro. These two workbooks are in the same folder. However, I plan on sharing the folder with others so that they can utilize my macro to run reports. If another user opens these files, will the VBA code update automatically to wherever the new user saves the folder?

If not, is there a script I can write to update the file path automatically? Or is there at least a way I can make it easy for users who don't know VBA to update the macro so it works on their PC?

Here is my formula:

```
"=IFERROR(IF(RC[-12]=""Adjustment"",VLOOKUP(R[-1]C[-11],'C:\Attendance Audits FINAL\Test Final Package\Kronos Only\[Kronos Adjustment.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R531C3,3,FALSE)-R[-1]C[-1],""""),0)"
```

I am not really an expert in VBA myself, but my initial thought is to define a variable that contains the filepath so users would only have to change the name of the variable.

```
dim FP as string
FP = 'C:\Attendance Audits FINAL\Test Final Package\Kronos Only\
```

So then my formula would become:

```
"=IFERROR(IF(RC[-12]=""Adjustment"",VLOOKUP(R[-1]C[-11],FP[Kronos Adjustment.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R531C3,3,FALSE)-R[-1]C[-1],""""),0)"
```

I am not sure this will work. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you share your code, the address of the cell(s), and the excel formula that should be in the cell(s) after the code runs?

Comment: You can easily test this your self by copying both files to a different folder on your local drive...  See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-link-management-and-storage-in-excel-46628e8d-2cd6-db5f-3474-f8d7144b09d6  "If the linked file and the source data file are in the same folder, only the file name is stored"

Comment: @VBasic2008 Is the code I included in the problem not enough? That includes the code that produces the formula after the code runs

Comment: @TimWilliams So if I am understanding correctly, if both of the workbooks are in the same folder, I can reference one from the other in a formula using ```=[book.xlsx]Sheet1!``` instead of ```fullpath[book.xlsx]Sheet1!```?

Comment: That seems to be the case, yes.

Comment: @TimWilliams It seems that it is not a problem when the workbooks are in the same folder. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I quite understand your question but you can use this line to get the filepath regardless of the user:
`ThisWorkbook.Path()`

Comment: Apologies that it wasn't clear. Basically, the user will have a workbook open (call it workbook 1). Within this workbook, there is a formula that extracts data from another, closed workbook (call it workbook 2).   I'd like to find a good way to update the file path for workbook 2 to include in the macro for workbook 1. Currently, the macro for workbook 1 uses the file path for workbook 2, but it is only specific to my PC. Is there a way to update the macro for workbook 1 to extract data from workbook 2 regardless of the user?

Comment: Yes, I think your macro can use the ```workbook2.path()``` method. Every workbook has this method available. I think you may have to open the workbook, but if you want it to appear as if the workbook were not open then you can set ```Application.visible =False```

Comment: Ok, say I get the new filepath for workbook 2. Can I then use a variable in the macro for workbook 1 to store the filepath, and use this variable in the formula from the original post instead of the actual filepath?
For example, can I do ```dim Var as string``` ```Var = filepath``` and the include Var in my formula instead of the long filepath?

Comment: So you wouldn't be able to store it in a variable because when the code execution is complete the variables are erased. You could save the variable into a cell of a hidden sheet and then the formula can reference that cell like this:
```workbook1.sheets("HiddenSheet").Range("A1").Value = workbook2.path()``` and then in your formula: ```=HiddenSheet!A1```. Does that work for you?

Comment: i don't think so because the formula requires ```filepath[name.xlsx]Sheet1!``` and I believe ```workbook2.path()``` will not give that.

Comment: to be clear, the formula I am using is defined in my macro

Comment: I see, so you don't want the filepath of workbook2, you want the full filename (filepath + file name). You can get this by: ```workbook2.FullName()```. This should return the filepath to the file + the name of the file itself. So you can add this in your formula via string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure the two workbooks are in the same folder you can use the below code to replace your FP string.

### Edit

Credit to VBasic2008 for this clearer code:

```
FP = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
```

Also, your code is going enter the letters "FP" into your formula instead of the value of the FP string. You need to concatenate like this:

```
"=IFERROR(IF(RC[-12]=""Adjustment"",VLOOKUP(R[-1]C[-11]," & FP & "[Kronos Adjustment.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R531C3,3,FALSE)-R[-1]C[-1],""""),0)"
```

Comment: It's kind of easier just to do `FP = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"`. Also, the first single quote `'` is missing.

Comment: `...C[-11],'" &...`

Answer (score 0):

### Copy a Formula

- In Excel, e.g. for the cell `M2` you can do:

```vb
=IFERROR(IF(A2="Adjustment",VLOOKUP(B1,'[Kronos Adjustment.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$531,3,FALSE)-L1,""),0)
```

For the cells above and to the left, you will get wrong (unexpected) results.

- In VBA you can use:

```vb
"=IFERROR(IF(RC[-12]=""Adjustment"",VLOOKUP(R[-1]C[-11],'[Kronos Adjustment.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R531C3,3,FALSE)-R[-1]C[-1],""""),0)"
```

Don't forget the first single quote `'`.

**A VBA Practical Example**

```
Sub WriteFormula()
    
    ' Source
    Const swbName As String = "Kronos Adjustment.xlsx"
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const slRow As Long = 531
    Const sfCol As Long = 1
    Const slCol As Long = 3
    Const sCritCol As Long = 3
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1" ' unknown
    Const dAddress As String = "M2:M21" ' unknown, possibly calculated
    Const drMin As Long = 2
    Const dcMin As Long = 13
    ' Both
    Const Criteria As String = "Adjustment"
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dAddress)
    ' Validate because there maybe unexpected results.
    With drg ' or With drg.Cells(1)
        If .Row < drMin Then Exit Sub
        If .Column < dcMin Then Exit Sub
    End With
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = dwb.Path
    
    ' Since the files are in the same folder, you could
    ' replace 'FolderPath & "\' with '"' in the formula
    ' and remove the previous line.
    ' But this could become useful e.g.
    ' in the case of 'FolderPath = dwb.Path & "\" & SubFolderName'.
    
    Dim dFormula As String
    dFormula = "=IFERROR(IF(RC[" & 1 - dcMin & "]=""" & Criteria _
        & """," & "VLOOKUP(R[" & 1 - drMin & "]C[" & 2 - dcMin _
        & "]," & "'" & FolderPath & "\[" & swbName & "]" & sName _
        & "'!" & "R" & sfRow & "C" & sfCol & ":R" & slRow & "C" & slCol _
        & "," & sCritCol & ",FALSE)-R[" & 1 - drMin _
        & "]C[" & 12 - dcMin & "],""""),0)"
    'Debug.Print dFormula
    
    drg.Formula = dFormula

End Sub
```